# @Element annotation needs to be added on all fields?

Tags: java, annotations, element, simple-framework

If I have a class with 20 fields, do I need to add @Element annotation on each of them? Is there a way to tell simple-framework to take all?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use the [**`@Default`**](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Default.html) annotation:

> The `Default` annotation is used to specify that all fields or methods
>   should be serialized in a default manner. This basically allows an
>   objects fields or properties to be serialized without the need to
>   annotate them.

In addition to `@Default` you can still use custom annotations as `@Element`:

```
@Root
@Default
public static class Example
{
    private int value = 3;
    private String string = "abc";

    @Element(name = "some-custom-name")
    private String customString = "custom";

    // ...
}
```

**Output:**

```
<example>
   <value>3</value>
   <string>abc</string>
   <some-custom-name>custom</some-custom-name>
</example>
```